# Saving a disk image containing both Ubuntu and Windows partitions to an external hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd, disk-image

I want a disk image of my computer hard drive, with both Ubuntu 16.04 (three ext4 Linux partitions `/home`, `/` and `/swap` within an extended partition) and Windows (NTFS partitions). I have an external hard drive formatted as FAT, which I initially thought was the best format since compatible with both Ubuntu and Windows.

However, when I have tried to create an image of the whole disk using gnome-disk-utility, I got a `File too large (g-io-error-quark,0)` error message. Is that inherent to backing up in FAT32 as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46437/why-cant-i-copy-a-5g-file?)?

Two follow-up questions:

- Can I back up in NTFS the whole disk without weird outcomes for my linux partitions? I care less about my Windows partitions -- would it be wiser then to format the external hard drive as ext4?
- Should I give up and back up (copy-and-paste) my partitions individually?

Comment: FAT only supports files no larger than 4gb. You won't have the same problem with NTFS. And EXT4 as well.

Comment: Define "exact copy" - does this include empty blocks or not?

Comment: You can't back up a Ubuntu OS partition (like `/`) to a FAT or NTFS file system, as your file permissions will be lost.

Comment: Look into using [Clonezilla](https://www.clonezilla.org/) to create a backup image of your entire drive to one file.

Comment: I would like a functioning disk image - not sure whether empty blocks could change this? I would like to be able to reinstall the disk image on another computer and be able to work identically as with my old computer drive

Comment: @Terrance :). Regarding OP external drive, what he has to have in mind is that if he formats the drive in EXT4, won't be read by windows.

Comment: @FredB If your other computer is not the same as your actual, windows may not function at all. You know, it's very complicated regarding changes of hardware.

Comment: @Fiximan I edited accordingly.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Many thanks for this info! It starts to look like I should just back up my Linux partitions as ext4...

Comment: You can try though, I've succesfully clone a disk with windows 7 to another  similar hardware, but had to reinstall many drivers.

Comment: You do not really need to do a image backup of Ubuntu. You can reinstall and restore your data. So just backup /home, perhaps any settings you changed in /etc and a list of installed apps. Data for apps is in /home. New install & restore can take less than an hour. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997
& https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2368992

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly this from Windows using  [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)

I can recommend it. Just select the partitions you want to back up when defining the backup. Don’t forget to make a recovery disc or usb stick.

Note that the Linux partitions are cloned. To my knowledge you cannot get at individual files. However you can mount the image of the Windows partitions in Windows as an additional drive (eg H:) and copy an individual file.

However the main use of this is to restore the entire image in one process. Useful to change an HDD for an SSD